# How to call inherited symbol that computed!? as Function in extended class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

First of all I'm a newbie in Typescript so title may be inaccurate because I don't know how that code works properly.

I'm using the [Klasa framework](https://klasa.js.org/#/) which is a [Discord](https://discordapp.com/) bot framework made top of [Discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js). They recently added plugin functionality and there is lots of examples written in regular ES6...

```
const { Client, util: { mergeDefault } } = require('klasa');
const DriverStore = require('../lib/structures/DriverStore');
const { OPTIONS } = require('../lib/util/constants');

class MusicClient extends Client {

    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
        this.constructor[Client.plugin].call(this);
    }

    static [Client.plugin]() {
        mergeDefault(OPTIONS, this.options);
        this.drivers = new DriverStore(this);
        this.registerStore(this.drivers);
     }
}

module.exports = MusicClient;
```

Type of `Client.plugin` is Symbol. How this code work? And how can I achieve something similar to this with TypeScript or it is doable?

I tried doing it like this:

```
import { KlasaClientOptions, Client } from "klasa"

export class ExtendedClient extends Client {
    public prop: string;
    constructor(options: KlasaClientOptions) {
        super(options);
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type 'typeof KlasaClient' has no index signature. 
        this.constructor[Client.plugin].call(this);
        // Also trying to use ExtendedClient.plugin.call() gives me 
        // Property 'call' does not exist on type 'symbol'
    }

    static [Client.plugin]() {
        // Property 'prop' does not exist of type 'typeof ExtendedClient'
        this.prop = "somestring";
    }
}
```

Edit: I fixed the error after I found out `static [Client.plugin]()` has the context of `KlasaClient` so I changed it as

```
import { KlasaClientOptions, Client } from "klasa"

export class ExtendedClient extends Client {
    public prop: string;
    constructor(options: KlasaClientOptions) {
        super(options);
        (this.constructor as any)[Client.plugin].call(this);

    }

    static [Client.plugin](this: ExtendedClient) {
        this.prop = "somestring";
    }

}
```

and the problems are solved...

Comment: The "ES6" example you've quoted is fairly poor, where exactly did you find it?

Comment: This was from an npm package, but there is another example from official dirigeants 

https://github.com/dirigeants/klasa-dashboard-hooks/blob/master/src/lib/Client.js

It's the same thing again I think...

Comment: https://github.com/dirigeants/klasa/blob/master/src/lib/Client.js#L317

This is how it loads plugins from here, so I think I solved the errors as doing

`(this.constructor as any)[Client.plugin].call(this);` and 

```    static [Client.plugin](this: ExtendedClient) {
        // Property 'prop' does not exist of type 'typeof ExtendedClient'
        this.prop = "somestring";
    }
```

Comment: Re your first link there, it's very odd practice. It's defining the method `static`, but calling it as though it were an instance method. It should just be an instance method. But if that's how it's defined, you have to work with it...

Comment: But I still don't know how it works... All I know is `this.constructor` is for accessing static properties and symbol is for meta-programming in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fairly odd, and unless there's a **strong** design constraint forcing it to be that way, it's not best practice.

It's defining a `static` method, but calling it as though it were an instance method. Which is part of why TypeScript is having issues with it.

The key parts are:

- This:

  ```
  static [Client.plugin]() {
      this.registerStore(this.drivers);
  }
  ```

  ...which defines a static method (a method on the constructor function) with the name from `Client.plugin` (which you've said is a Symbol, but it doesn't really matter whether it's a Symbol or a string).
- And this in the constructor:

  ```
  this.constructor[Client.plugin].call(this);
  ```

  ...which is what's calling it as though it were an instance method. `this.constructor` accesses the constructor function that created `this` (loosely speaking, that's not entirely accurate), and so `this.constructor[Client.plugin]` accesses the static method with the name from `Client.plugin`. Then `.call(this)` calls that method, but sets `this` as `this` during the call, a though it were an instance method. So within the call to `Client.plugin`, `this` is an *instance* of the class (whereas normally `this` would be the constructor function).

Which is very odd.

In terms of making TypeScript okay with it, I think I'd probably approach it like this:

```
import { KlasaClientOptions, Client } from "klasa";

export class ExtendedClient extends Client {
    public prop: string;
    constructor(options: KlasaClientOptions) {
        super(options);
        (this.constructor as any)[Client.plugin].call(this);
    }

    static [Client.plugin]() {
        const inst = this as ExtendedClient;
        // Now use `inst` instead of `this` where your example code uses `this`, so:
        inst.prop = "somestring";
    }
}
```

The key bits are:

- This:

  ```
  (this.constructor as any)[Client.plugin].call(this);
  ```

  ...by using `any` we defeat TypeScript's type checking, but we basically have to for this odd structure.
- And this:

  ```
  const inst = this as ExtendedClient;
  ```

  ...by using `as ExtendedClient` we're telling TypeScript that although normally it would expect `this` to be the constructor function, it's actually an `ExtendedClient`. We do that once with a constant to avoid having to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: I forgot to check answers as I'm editing the question but the good thing is now I understand how it works... There is a last piece that stuck in my mind... 

[There](github.com/dirigeants/klasa/blob/master/src/lib/Client.js#L317) it loads the plugin as it calls the static property within Client's context so it is okay to do it as my code edited as in question post, or this `const inst = this as ExtendedClient;` both way there is a casting so its fine to do it as both ways?

Comment: @DenizCan - They're two different ways to end up being able to set `props` in a way that TypeScript is happy with. If this is the **only** way it will be called (and I think it is), then I'd say your way is better than the above. You should post it as an answer (not an edit to the question). It's not just okay to answer your own question, but encouraged. :-)